# ffmpeg show audio codecs supported by container format and video codec

Tags: audio, video, ffmpeg, codec

To automate scripts for manipulating video files, I would like to get a list of supported audio codecs - ideally with their encoder names - based on a video codec and container format (might also be known as muxer or demuxer), as supported by `ffmpeg`.

Find out the video codec using:

```
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_entries stream=codec_name \
  -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 video.mp4
```

which returns `h264`. Find out the container format using:

```
ffprobe -v error -select_streams v:0 -show_format_entry format_name \
  -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 video.mp4
```

Which returns `mov,mp4,m4a,3gp,3g2,mj2`.

We assume the input video file has no audio stream, so we can't simply use:

```
ffprobe -v error -select_streams a:0 -show_entries \
  stream=codec_name -of default=noprint_wrappers=1:nokey=1 video.mp4
```

which would otherwise return `aac`.

The commands in https://stackoverflow.com/a/20587693/188159 might have the solution but I haven't been able to figure out how to filter them.

Comment: Maybe I don't quite follow what you're trying to do, but `ffmpeg` will automatically choose an appropriate audio encoder based on the output format. You can view the default encoders, for your particular `ffmpeg`, with `ffmpeg -h muxer=mp4`. I'm not sure why you need a list of supported audio formats per output container format. Your "format" and "codec" commands are mislabeled by the way (swap them).